# making a full size panel, with grid bag layout

Tags: java, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I am making a program with 3 **JSliders**, `for r,g,b and i` want to add a panel that will change it's color for the chosen color in the sliders, everything works for me except one thing, I don't know how to make the panel in the full size of the screen, this is the best I could do, but this is still kind of small and I want to make the panel full size. can any one show me how to do it?
The program is kind of long so I will only send the part of the **gridbaglayout** and the panel.

```
private JPanel panel;

public delta(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0 ,0 ,0));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 6;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 3;
    add(panel ,c);
```

Comment: See my edit to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your panel to Jframe

**jframe.add(yourpanel)**

This code without any Layout will fill the window.

**Edit:**

```
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(500,500);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JLabel label = new JLabel("HELLO");
            frame.add(label);
```

This fills the **JFrame** with **JLabel**.

Comment: thanks, i did it and the panel is full size, just one last thing, how can i make it a backround?(that all the ather stuff will be above him)

Comment: Put everything inside the jpanel. that is it

Comment: @talnisan I've just seen all your comments including your code, for future questions you make, be sure to clic the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26532691/edit) button on your question, so you can add the code there and not in a lot of comments. Will make it easier to read for us and also copy-paste it. Good Luck.